# Executing a MATLAB script from Java gives EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION error

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab

I am trying to call a MATLAB function from Java, using Eclipse. I am using MATLAB R2018b (the trial version), JDK 11.0.1, and Eclipse 2018-09. Both MATLAB and Eclipse are 64 bit versions. I am on a Windows 64 bit machine.

I am using the `MatlabEngine`, as per this example:
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/execute-matlab-functions-from-java.html

If I try to run the following code snippet (copied verbatim from the above link) from my `main` method

```
MatlabEngine eng = MatlabEngine.startMatlab();
double[] a = {2.0, 4.0, 6.0};
double[] roots = eng.feval("sqrt", a);
for (double e : roots) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
eng.close();
```

... I get the following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000005700000b95, pid=11028, tid=11252
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (11.0.1+13) (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# v  ~StubRoutines::atomic_add_long
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# F:\research\software\code\eclipse_workspace\tests\hs_err_pid11028.log
Could not load hsdis-amd64.dll; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I tried Googling the error message, but to no avail. What is going on here?

Comment: Did you try reading `F:\research\software\code\eclipse_workspace\tests\hs_err_pid11028.log`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I did - it starts with the same error message, and then continues with a lot of detail in which I get lost.

Comment: I can confirm that this also happens on IntelliJ 2018.3.2 x64 (i.e. it's not an Eclipse-specific issue). Win 10 and R2018b here. [This](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/313057) might be related.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this exact error (but with Matlab R2020b). For anyone still interested, swiching the runtime JRE from JDK11 to JDK-8.0.275.1 solved the problem.